# How can I execute a command inputted by the user as a turtle command?

Tags: python, input, command, turtle-graphics

I need to be able to ask a user for a turtle command such as forward(90) and execute it as a turtle command, e.g turtle.forward(90) and repeat until the user exits.
so far I have:

```
def turtle_input(prompt):
"""Loop to ask for user input and execute as a turtle command"""
import turtle
while True:
    t = input('Enter a turtle command: ')
    if t in ['Quit' , 'quit', 'q', 'Q']:
        break
    turtle.(t)     
return prompt
```

Comment: Unless you are using python 3, you probably want `raw_input()` and not `input()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executing arbitrary code is usually not a good idea as it is a huge security vulnerability, but here's one way:

```
eval('turtle.{0}'.format(t))
```

This isn't a good idea as consider the following string a user could pass in:

```
t = 'forward(90) or __import__("os").system("rm -rf ~")'
```

All of a sudden, your home directory starts to get deleted -- Oops.

---

A slightly less robust, but more secure solution might be to use `ast.literal_eval` and parse the string yourself:

```
import ast

#...
funcname,args = t.split('(',1)
args = ast_literal_eval('('+args)
if hasattr(args,'__iter__'):
    getattr(turtle,funcname)(*args)
else:
    getattr(turtle,funcname)(args)
```

Comment: That's worked thanks! An it's only going to be for private use so I don't think I'll be typing that in! Just out of curiosity what would be a more secure option?

Comment: You can do things to make `eval` more secure.  (check the string to make sure that nothing has a `__` in it, restrict the namespace `eval` has access to, etc.).  Otherwise, you'd have to actually parse your string. It might not be too bad though.  I'll update in a second...

Comment: On the other hand, the person could type in 'import os' and then 'os.sytem('del C:')' which has no underscores but still would kill your computer.

Comment: @Kevin -- That falls under the "restrict the namespace" clause.  Note that `'import os'` will fail in a bare eval since it isn't an _expression_, it's a _statement_.

Comment: Oh well a lot of havoc can be caused; if they already imported os then os.system('del C:') (i think) would work, or input could simply be entered that would crash the program.

Comment: @Kevin -- Of course they could crash the program, but there isn't a whole lot of _danger_ there.  As far as if they already imported `os`, that's what I'm talking about with restricting the namespace.  `eval` can take up to 3 arguments, the second and third arguments are mappings that hold the global and local namspaces that `eval` should use.  If you pass those in without `os` (and make sure they the user can't get to is using `__builtins__`) then you're _somewhat_ safe.  Anyway, this is a bit of a non-argument.  I already mentioned that it isn't safe and provided an alternative...

Comment: Yeah... Sorry, I didn't want to make it an argument. I was just attempting to enforce your assertion that eval is not safe (and I probably failed.)

Comment: @Kevin -- I think when it comes to the safety of `eval` in python, everybody should read [Ned Batchelder's blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) on the subject at least once... :-).  And after you start to understand the wizardry that he does to gain access to other objects and/or segfault the interpretter you really gain appreciation for how scary `eval` is.

Comment: @mgilson Already read that. XD Also I just realized eval looks/sounds like evil.